# JSON File Formatting using Python RegEx

Tags: python, regex

So I have a few json datasets and the part im dealing with looks like this.

```
"transcriptionData": {
               "content": "[lang:Foreign] Air Force [/lang:Foreign ...[lang:Foreign] target [/lang:Foreign] ..."
            }
```

Under content we have [lang:Foreign]. However, it is not like that all the time. In my dataset there are a lot of strings that are incorrectly formatted. For example, [/lang:F , [lang.Foreign] , M.L.A.lang:Foreign], [lang:Foreing], Lang:Foreign], [langForeign], [l/ang:Foreign].

The Correct result should look like the following.
When the language changes the beginning should look like `< lang: Foreign >` and when the translation ends it should end with `< /lang: Foreign >`

I have tried this the following.

```
trans = re.sub(r'\[(lang[^\[\]]*)\]', r'<\1>', trans)
```

which works some time, but not all the time. For example, if the string is Lang:Foreign], I want to have an opening brackets as well as <>.

```
trans = re.sub(r'\[/(lang[^\[\]]*)\]', r'</\1>', trans)
```

I have tried this as well but dont work all the time.

The Correct result should look like `< lang: Foreign >` and `< /lang: Foreign >`. Please let me know if there is any suggestions.

Comment: Potentially missing the [, ], or : with garbage characters included ? This will be a tough one. I'll try to answer but there must be some consistency for the poor regex engine to rely on. Any output of this apparently malformed file will likely output just as corrupt.

Comment: @DaryllChandler I agree thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your regex to also catch some of the edge cases for you but it's not going to correct every possibly typo if the data is that poorly formatted. Especially if it is missing closing or opening brackets there is no way for

Start with yours, it can successfully get lang:whatever or lang.whatever: `\[(lang[^\[\]]*)\]`

Then add check for bogus characters before opening [ bracket `[^[]*\[(lang[^\[\]]*)\]`

Then make opening [ bracket optional `[^[]*\[?(lang[^\[\]]*)\]`

Then add check for bogus characters after opening [ bracket `[^[]*\[?[^\/]*(lang[^\[\]]*)\]`

Finally, if there is no closing ] bracket, stop on a space `[^[]*\[?[^\/]*(lang[^\[\]]*)\][\]|\s]`

Here you go: https://regex101.com/r/tuaPl3/1